# Longest run of integers in an array in assembly x86

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

I am having trouble finding the longest run of integers in an array in x86 assembly. I have an array I am passing in, and the size of the array, and I think I am on track with my logic, just can't figure out the last steps. Any help is appreciated. This is the code I have so far:

```
int  Longest_Run(int nums[], int siz) {
    //
    int returnValue = 0;
    int freq[101] = { 0 };  //if needed
    int arr_length = 0;


    arr_length = sizeof(nums) / sizeof(int); //WRONG

    __asm {
        //LONGEST RUN. Return value to caller :

        MOV ECX, siz // arr_length //For looping
        //LEA ESI, nums //ptr to array
        mov ESI, nums //ptr to array
        //LEA EDI, nums //ptr to array
        MOV EBX, 0 //Frequency counter
        MOV EAX, [ESI] //First array int in SI

        L1:
        CMP EAX, [ESI] //Compare 1st int with 1st int
            JE L2
            JMP L3
        L4:
            LOOP L1
        JMP CLEAR

            L2 :  //If equal
            INC EBX //Inc counter  
            ADD ESI, 4 //Inc to 2nd item in array
            MOV EAX, [ESI] //Move 2nd item into AX
            JMP L1


        L3 :
        PUSH EBX // Puts counter int on stack
            MOV EBX, 0 // Clears BX to start over
            ADD ESI, 4 //Inc to 3rd item in array
            MOV EAX, [ESI] //Move 3rd item into AX
            JMP L4


            CLEAR:

            POP EDX
            MOV EDX, returnValue


            //END

    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Any ideas or guidance?

Comment: It might generate better answers if you edit your question to include your algorithm.

Comment: You always do `MOV EAX, [ESI]` before `CMP EAX, [ESI]` so obviously they will always be equal.

Comment: Don't use push/pop mixed with branches; it's extremely easy to end up not popping everything you pushed.  If you run out of registers, you can use another named variable, which the compiler will allocate space for on the stack.  (But you haven't used EDI or EDX yet.)